# Error pushing assets to Heroku when using Sass helpers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, sass

I'm trying to push my rails project to Heroku but when it compiles it seems that SASS doesn't recognise the helpers `asset-url, asset-path, image-url, etc` .

Error message:

```
Sass::SyntaxError: Invalid CSS after "@import ": expected file to import (string or url()), was "asset-url("some-..."
```

This is exactly the line that contains the helper:

```
@import asset-url("some-file.css");
```

This is my config/environment/production.rb file (only relevant lines):

```
  config.serve_static_assets = true
  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
  config.assets.css_compressor = :sass
  config.assets.compile = true
  config.assets.digest = true
```

Here is my config/assets.rb file (only relevant lines):

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile = ['*.js', '*.css', '*.css.scss']
```

Since production rails server has the digest filename feature, I must use this helpers but I can't find any solution for this problem.

The following are things I've done:

- Rename file extension from .css to .css.scss
- Change config.assets.version from 1.0 to 1.1 to rebuild assets
- Use rails helpers instead of sass helpers <%= asset_path("file.css") %> and change filenames from .css to .css.erb , this doesn't work either.

What can be the problem here??

Answer (score 0):

Rename your file to .scss and import it directly (scss extension is not needed in the import):

```
@import asset-url("some-file");
```